# how to use firebase storage bucket node sdk

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

the code is super simple

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fecha = require('fecha');

admin.initializeApp({
    serviceAccountId: '<service-account>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',


      databaseURL: "<database-url>",
        storageBucket: "<storage-bucket>",
        projectId: "<project-id>"
    });

    const storage = admin.storage();

   // console.log(storage.bucket().ref('/general/reviews/1/test.jpg'));
    console.log(storage.ref('/general/reviews/1/file.txt').putString('casacasacasa'));
```

i put this code into a cloud function but it crashes

```
 storage.bucket(...).ref is not a function at exports.madrid (/workspace/index.js:666:30) at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:100:17) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

and if i uncomment the first line it goes

```
TypeError: storage.ref is not a function at exports.madrid (/workspace/index.js:666:21) at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:100:17) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

i'm 100% the bucket exists and this very same code on the android sdk works fine...
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care if you use `firebase-admin` for `storage` you have to follow the documentation : https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/

With `firebase-admin` the `ref` function is replace by `file` like this :

`admin.storage().bucket().file(remotePath).save(buffer)`